# Launch Plane9 windowed from Logitech G Hub

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, logitech-keyboard

I have a "music" profile set up on my Logitech G815 keyboard, and I wanted to use a G key to launch Plane9 windowed mode. I theory this seems simple. https://www.plane9.com/Wiki/cmdline shows that I can run the program with the `-w` option, and indeed the shortcut located in `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Plane9` has the `-w` option in the target like so `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Plane9\Plane9.exe" -w`

I've tried to mimic this with the following set up

[image]

However when trying the key out, I *do* get a windowed mode come up, however the screen is just black within, whereas if I launch either via the windows menu, or using the shortcut in the start menu folder, it works fine.

It's worth noting the title of the window when it works briefly shows "Plane9 Visualizer" before then showing "Plane9 v2.5.1.3", whereas using the keyboard G key, I see only the second title window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, when trying the key out, I get Plane9 in windowed mode but the screen is just black.

This seems to be a quirk of Plane9. Attempting to execute `Plane9.exe` directly from (at least some) external sources appears to result in the problem above (Plane9 starting, but no visualization being displayed).

A simple fix for this is to "execute" a standard Windows `.lnk` (Windows shortcut link) file with your preferred options e.g.:

*ex. Plane9 - Windowed.lnk*

[image: Plane9 - Windowed Link - Screenshot]

Unfortunately, I don't have the application you're using in order to test its ability to execute `.lnk` files. But you can create a `.lnk` file to `Plane9.exe` with the `-w` option (as shown above) and try using e.g. `"C:\path\to\Plane9 - Windowed.lnk"` in your application's `File Path` field.

If this doesn't work, I might try using the batch file example below and executing that in your application's `File Path` field instead (ex. `"C:\path\to\Plane9 - Windowed.bat"`).

---

*Note that if you want to use the same general options as in your original screenshot, you do not necessarily need to include `-w` in the `Target` field of the `lnk` file. That is, you may be able to use ex. `Target: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Plane9\Plane9.exe"` in your `.lnk` file and simply use `-w` in the `Arguments` field, as shown in your original screenshot.*

---

**Other `.lnk` Execution Examples**

***Batch***

*ex. Plane9 - Windowed.bat*

```
"C:\path\to\Plane9 - Windowed.lnk"
```

You can add `%*` to this batch file if you need to pass (additional) command line parameters ex.:

*ex. Plane9 - Windowed.bat*

```
"C:\path\to\Plane9 - Windowed.lnk" %*
```

Allowing e.g. `"Plane9 - Windowed.bat" --width 600 --height 400`.

***Python***

*ex. Plane9 - Windowed.py (Python 3 on Windows)*

```
# Example demonstrating how to execute Windows ".lnk" files with Python.

# Native Python module for running external applications, etc.
import subprocess

# Either of the subprocess calls below will work when executing Windows .lnk files.

# subprocess.run('cmd /c "C:\\path\\to\\Plane9 - Windowed.lnk"')
subprocess.run('"C:\\path\\to\\Plane9 - Windowed.lnk"', shell=True)
```

`sys.argv` (imported from the native Python [sys](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html) module) can be used to capture variables from the command line for use with `subprocess.run()` (similar to `%*` in batch), if needed.

---

*This Python example assumes Python is installed on your system. In particular, it was tested with a vanilla Windows Python installation from [python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/), configured to execute `.py` files from the command line.*

---

**Command Window Minimization Wrapper**

Both the `Plane9 - Windowed.bat` and `Plane9 - Windowed.py` examples above will spawn a command window before starting Plane9. This command window is safe to close completely (exit) once Plane9 is running.

That said, if you just want a quick way to minimize this command window automatically to the taskbar (i.e. you don't want to take extra steps to hide the window completely or kill it entirely, etc.), you can leverage the Windows `start` command in a second batch file to accomplish this:

*ex. Start Plane9.bat*

```
start /min "" "C:\path\to\Plane9 - Windowed.bat"
```

or:

*ex. Start Plane9.bat*

```
start /min "" "C:\path\to\Plane9 - Windowed.py"
```

Note that you can add `%*` to this batch file as well if you need to capture command line parameters (as above).

Comment: Very nice and full answer thanks. The first solution didn't work as G Hub takes the .lnk file properties and just seems to read the direct path so ends up putting that in the file path instead. I did get the .bat file to work, however the program didn't work with the .py file. It's a little inconvenient that the cmd window remains open, but not a big deal really. Thanks very much!

Comment: Your welcome. I am glad to hear you got it working. =)